# 3次元プロットにおける、グリッド線、軸の設定に関して

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

はじめまして、初投稿です。
以下の図のグリッド線を消したく、以下のコードを書きました。

```
ax.grid(color="white")
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: 変化後]
ただ、これだと、軸の目盛りが消えてしまい、軸の目盛りを変化前にのようにつけたいのですが、どのような操作をすればよいでしょうか？
ちなみに、`ax.set_ticks([])`の`[]`を変えたら、

[image: 変化前]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])
```

の箇所はコメントアウトして

```
ax.grid(False)
```

を追加してみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます！！できました。